# XPages DateTextBox - setting constraints

Tags: javascript, dojo, xpages

I am working with the date text box and had a few questions.  This is with designer 9, so its using dojo 1.8 not that it should make too much difference.

Setting Min / Max dates

I don't see a way to do this in designer.  There isn't anything in xe:djDateTimeConstraints that matches, so is this something I need to do via javascript?
I have an example below that changes the EndDate control once StartDate is selected, but didn't see a way to set StartDate other then beforeRenderResponse or some such.

Selectable Dates

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/form/DateTextBox.html
"also validates against developer-provided constraints like min, max, valid days of the week, etc."

Valid days of the week - I'd love to set it to just weekdays that are selectable, but there is no example, and the link does not go to a page with a dayofweek constraint.  What term should I be searching for?  In the example below I have a validator, but I didn't know if the date text box could just have the weekends be unselectable.

Here is my example control - when start date is set, it changes constraints of end date

```
<xp:label value="Start Date" id="lblStartDate"></xp:label>
<xe:djDateTextBox id="djDateStart">
    <xe:this.constraints>
        <xe:djDateTimeConstraints datePattern="M/dd/yyyy"></xe:djDateTimeConstraints>
    </xe:this.constraints>
    <xp:eventHandler event="onChange" submit="false">
        <xe:this.script><![CDATA[
        var startDateID = "#{id:djDateStart}";
        var endDateID = "#{id:djDateEnd}";
        var hiddenEndDateID = "#{id:hiddenEndDate}";

    require(["dojo/date/locale"], function(locale){
        var x = new Date (dojo.byId(startDateID).value);
          // Fails if current date is the weekend or empty
        if(locale.isWeekend(x) || dojo.byId(startDateID).value == "") {
            dojo.style(hiddenEndDateID, "display", "none");
            dojo.byId(endDateID).value = "";
            dojo.byId(startDateID).value = "";
            dijit.byId(startDateID).displayMessage("dates must be weekdays");
        } else {
            // Set display value and constraint for End Date
            dojo.byId(endDateID).value = dojo.byId(startDateID).value;
            dijit.byId(endDateID).constraints.min =  arguments[0];
            dijit.byId(endDateID).constraints.max = dojo.date.add(arguments[0], "week", 3);

            // Make End Date and Comment visible. 
            dojo.style(hiddenEndDateID, "display", "inline");
        }
    })
    ]]></xe:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xe:djDateTextBox>
```

Comment: Don't know that I can set min/max constraints in designer, so I instead went with creating a script block on the page that would set the values when dojo was ready.  Not optimal but at least it works.  Still not sure if its possible to restrict users from selecting weekends via UI like the website alluded to, but I've got validators to warn users.

Answer (score 0):

the solution I came up with was to use the Range check - not constraints.  So in the script block below, it returns false when the day is sunday/saturday (0, 6) and if its not within the range.

Perhaps this will help someone else.

```
        fyStart = new Date ("#{applicationScope.fyStart}");
        fyEnd = new Date ("#{applicationScope.fyEnd}");
        calendarEnd = new Date ("#{applicationScope.calendarEnd}");

    require(["dojo/ready", "dojo/parser", "dijit/registry", "dijit/Dialog"], function(ready, parser, registry){
         ready(function(){

            dijit.byId('#{id:djDateStart}').rangeCheck = function(date,constraints) {
                var day=date.getDay();
                return day !==0 && day !== 6 &&  date >=  fyStart && date <=  calendarEnd;
            }
            dijit.byId('#{id:djDateEnd}').rangeCheck = function(date,constraints) {
                var day=date.getDay();
                return day !==0 && day !== 6 &&  date >= fyStart && date <=  calendarEnd;
            }

        });
    });
```